# Batch File For Creating .txt with computer names and Teamviewer Numbers

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, command-prompt, teamviewer

I have been trying to figure out how to get a list of computers and their team viewer IDs. At this point I have a file with computer names. The Batch file I started trying to write looks at that list of names creates a bridge to my machine then reports back the hostname and Teamviewer ClientID. The problem is that we have different versions of teamviewer installed and the location is not the same. When I run my batch file as it is it will give me teamviewer 7 ClientIDs but thats it. As this is my first batch file any help is greatly appreciated!

::Creates .txt file with hostname and Teamviewer ClientID on network location.

```
call net use x: \\server\location (Password) /user:(UserName)

call hostname >> x:\TeamviewerID.txt

for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer\Version7 /v ClientID') do (set /a num = %%a)
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 GOTO Print ELSE GOTO EIGHT

:EIGHT
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer\Version8 /v ClientID"') do (set /a num = %%a)
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 GOTO Print ELSE GOTO NINE

:NINE
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer /v ClientID') do (set /a num = %%a)
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 GOTO Print


:Print
echo Teamviewer ID is %num%>> x:\TeamviewerID.txt

call net use x: /delete
```

Answer (score 1):

First batch - brave!... and also Bravo!!

Let's take the `reg` command to start with. Bizarrely, `reg` does not set `errorlevel` to non-`0` if the requested key is missing. That's why ony the `version 7` part was being executed.

`reg query` with a missing key produces no output but it does produce an error message, ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.`The output string is sent to`stdout`and is the output that would be processed by the`do`part. The error string is sent to`stderr` which is normally assigned to the console.

So - first, let's force `num` to be "set" to *nothing*

```
set "num="
```

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned. `set /a` can safely be used "quoteless".

Batch is sensitive to spaces in a `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N" `set /a` is a later implementation which ignores this rule. (just a caution)

Then we can use a tickled version of your code

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer\Version7 /v ClientID 2^>nul') do (set /a num = %%a)
```

where the additional `2^>nul` redirects `stderr` messages to `nul` (ie *nowhere*). The caret `^` is called an `escape character` and is required here because the `>` is part of the `reg query` not part of the `for`. (the `>` is thus termed "escaped")

The result will be that if the key exists, the `set` will be executed and `num` will be assigned a value. If the key is missing, `num` will remain unchanged.

Remember, we initialised num to *nothing*? And we *may* now have set `num` to `something` (if the key exists?) so now we can test whether the variable has been set or not

```
if defined num goto print
```

(batch is largely case-insensitive)

So - a little excursion now into the syntax of `if`. In the action part, batch has no idea of whether the string `else` is some command's parameter or is the keyword `ELSE`. Consequently, we need to tell it:

```
if somebinarycondition (
 dothis_if_true
) else (
 dothis_if_false
)
```

or

```
if somebinarycondition (dothis_if_true) else (dothis_if_false)
```

The positioning of the parentheses is critical. The first open must be on the same physical line as the `if` (or **do**) and if an else is used then both the preceding `)` and succeeding `(` must occur on the same physical line as the `else`**and** there must be a space between the `else` keyword and the parentheses. This allows multiple lines to be conditionally executed. The parentheses are not required if the `else` clause is missing or on the `else` clause if only one command is required to be executed.

Batch simply executes instructions line-by-line until end-of-file or an `exit` statement is encountered, hence

```
if condition (goto there) else (goto here)
:here
```

is simpler written

```
if condition goto there
:here
```

so the instructions following the label `:here` would be executed if `condition` is false.

Hence, overall,

```
SET "num="
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer\Version7 /v ClientID 2^>nul') do (set /a num = %%a)
IF DEFINED num GOTO print 

:EIGHT
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer\Version8 /v ClientID" 2^>nul') do (set /a num = %%a)
IF DEFINED num GOTO print 

:NINE
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer /v ClientID 2^>nul') do (set /a num = %%a)
IF DEFINED num GOTO print 

echo Not found!
pause
goto :eof    

:Print
echo Teamviewer ID is %num%
```

Unlike many languages, batch has no concept of the end of a "procedure" - it simply continues execution line-by-line until it reaches the end-of-file. Consequently, you need to `goto :eof` after completing the mainline, otherwise execution will continue through the subroutine code. `:EOF` is a predefined label understood by `CMD` to mean `end of file`. The colon is **required**.

Comment: THANK YOU @Magoo! I don't want to vary too off topic but it is great to have such awesome support as I start partaking in such endeavors. I actually ended up getting it to work after a long afternoon at work but here is what I was able to gather. <br\>    for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer\Version7 /v ClientID') do (set /a num = %%a)
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (echo TeamViewer number is %num% ) else (echo not exists)